# Laravel validation - More readable messages

Tags: php, validation, laravel

Is there a simple way to replace the input name in Laravel's validation messages with for example a label?

Right now message is like:

> The usrRoleId field is required.

I know there are two options:

1. Change input names to more readable.
2. Write EACH message in the validation request to look like this: User Role is required.

I'm looking for something more automatic - like defining a string once and using it every time such field name is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can and it's actually quite easy. You can specify a custom name for a given attribute in your `resources/lang/en/validation.php` file under the `attributes` key:

```
'attributes' => [
    'usrRoleId' => 'User Role'
],
```

And now anywhere you have `usrRoleId` for the `:attribute` inside a validator message, it will be replaced with `User Role`. So instead of:

> The usrRoleId field is required.

You'll get the nice:

> The User Role field is required.

---

If you want to have a whole custom message not only a custom attribute name for when the `usrRoleId` is required, then you can add an entry for that user the `custom` key in the same file. So adding this:

```
'custom' => [
    'usrRoleId' => [
        'required' => 'User Role is required',
    ],
],
```

Will use that custom message but without an `:attribute` placeholder. If you want to use the placeholder you can leave the `attributes` mapping I described above:

```
'custom' => [
    'usrRoleId' => [
        'required' => ':attribute is required',
    ],
],
```

And you'll still get your custom message but with the mapped attribute name:

> User Role is required.

Comment: Many thanks :) This is exactly what I was looking for :)